# Model-based partitioning with "two-layer interaction" (segmented models)

Tags: r, tree, partitioning, party

I am trying to build a model-based tree with a type of "two-layer interaction" where the models in the nodes of the tree are segmented again.

I am using the `mob()` function to this aim but I could not manage to make the argument for the `fit` function work with the `lmtree()` function.

In the following example `a` is function of `b` and the relationship between `a` and `b` depends on `d` and on `b | d`.

```
library("partykit")
set.seed(321)

b <- runif(200)
d <- sample(1:2, 200, replace = TRUE)
a <- jitter(ifelse(d == 1, 2 * b - 1, 4 * b - 1.2), amount = .1)
a[b < .5 & d == 1] <- jitter(rep(0, length(a[b < .5 & d == 1])))
a[b < .3 & d == 2] <- jitter(rep(0, length(a[b < .3 & d == 2])))

fit <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ..., estfun = FALSE, object = FALSE)
{   
  x <- x[, 2]
  l <- lmtree(y ~ x | b)
  return(l)
}   

m <- mob(a ~ b | d, fit = fit) # not working
```

Of course with this simple example I could use `lmtree(a ~ b | d + b)` to find every interaction but is there a way to use as `fit` function of `mob()` a `lmtree()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No but yes ;-)

**No**, `lmtree()` cannot be used easily as a fitter for a `mob()`.

1. The dimension of the inner tree (`lmtree()`) is not fixed, i.e., you may get a tree without any partition or with many subgroups, and this would be confusing for the outer tree (`mob()`).
2. Even if one worked around the dimension issue or fixed it by always forcing one break, one would need more work to set up the right coefficient vector, matrix of estimating functions, etc. This is also not straightforward because the convergence rate (and hence the inference) is different if breakpoints are given (e.g., for a binary factor) or have to be estimated (such as for your numeric variables `b`).
3. The way you set up your `fit()` function, the inner `lmtree()` does not know where to find `b`. All it has is a numeric vector `y` and a numeric matrix `x` but not the original data.

**But yes**, I think that all of these issues can be addressed if changing the view from fitting a "two-layer" tree to fitting a "segmented" model inside a tree. My impression is that you want to fit a model `y ~ x` (or `a ~ b` in your example) where a piecewise linear function is used with an additional breakpoint in `x`. If the piecewise linear function is supposed to be continuous in `x`, then the `segmented` package can be easily used. If not, then `strucchange` could be leveraged. Assuming you want the former (as you have simulated your data like this), I include a worked `segmented` example below (and also slightly modified your question to reflect this).

Changing the names and code a little bit, your data `d` has a segmented piecewise linear relationship of `y ~ x` with coefficients depending on a group variable `g`.

```
set.seed(321)
d <- data.frame(
  x = runif(200),
  g = factor(sample(1:2, 200, replace = TRUE))
)
d$y <- jitter(ifelse(d$g == "1",
  pmax(0, 2 * d$x - 1),
  pmax(0, 4 * d$x - 1.2)
), amount = 0.1)
```

Within every node of a tree I can then fit a model `segmented(lm(y ~ x))` which comes with suitable extractors for `coef()`, `logLik()`, `estfun()` etc. Thus, the mobster function is simply:

```
segfit <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ...)
{
  x <- as.numeric(x[, 2])
  segmented::segmented(lm(y ~ x))
}
```

(Note: I haven't tried whether `segmented()` would also support `lm()` objects with `weights` and `offset`.)

With this we can obtain the full tree which simply splits in `g` in this basic example:

```
library("partykit")
segtree <- mob(y ~ x | g, data = d, fit = segfit)
plot(segtree, terminal_panel = node_bivplot, tnex = 2)
```

[image: segtree]

A hands-on introduction to `segmented` is available in: Muggeo VMR (2008). "**segmented**: An R Package to Fit Regression Models with Broken-Line Relationships." *R News*, **8**(1), 20-25.  https://CRAN.R-project.org/doc/Rnews/

For the underlying methodological background see: Muggeo VMR (2003). "Estimating Regression Models with Unknown Break-Points." *Statistics in Medicine*, **22**(19), 3055-3071. [doi:10.1002/sim.1545](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.1545)

Comment: Thanks :-) I was actually surprised how easy it was to put this together! But Vito's `segmented` was friendly enough to come with all the building blocks required by us. Now I'm curious to see how well it works in real data...

Comment: Thank you @AchimZeileis . Actually I used at first exactly this approach (segmented function for the fit). But I gave up with my real data as it takes days to run ... Anyway thanks again for the help.

Comment: @MassCorr Is the timing issue extremely different for `mob(y ~ x | ..., fit = segtree)` as opposed to `lmtree(y ~ x | ...)`? If the latter also takes so very long then it might be necessary to coarsen some regressors or factors to alleviate split point search, increase minimal segment size, restrict tree depth etc.

Comment: @AchimZeileis mob + segmented is taking much more time than lmtree

Comment: Ok, I see.  By how much approximately? Possibly one can play around with starting values etc. maybe some speed - ups are possible. Asking Vito might also be helpful...

Comment: @AchimZeileis Well even for the simplest model with a data sample it is >> 100 x . I think (but you know this better than me) that it is difficult for mob to converge with this kind of regression (specially with noisy data)

Comment: In addition segmented function itself tends to have difficulties to converge sometimes

Comment: Probably a good share of that time goes into formula processing and/or convergence problems. It might help to interface `seg.lm.fit(...)` rather than `segmented(lm(...))` and then set better starting values manually (e.g., using information from the mother node), relax convergence criteria etc.

Comment: This is a very good idea to use the information from the mother node ! I can try this

Comment: In `mob_control()` there is the `restart` parameter for this. And then the `fit` function gets the parameters from the mother node through the `start` argument. However, care is needed when using this. My experience is that it sometimes leads to speed-ups but sometimes it does not... or even results in convergence problems. Thus, the`fit` function should pay attention to this.

Comment: Ok will let you know how it goes